# Python - for cycle in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm trying to create a list with the number of days of each month between 1901 and 2000, but I can't manage to change the values properly.
Here's my code:

```
year = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
period = [year] * 100

for i in range(1901, 2001):
    if i % 4 == 0 and i % 100 != 0:
        period[i-1901][1] = 29

period[99][1] = 29
print period
```

When I execute it, the list that I get has 29 as second entry for every year, which I obviously do not want. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Minor comment on your logic but your code will assume 2000 wasn't a leap year but it was as all years divisible by 400 are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
period = [year] * 100
```

This creates a list containing 100 references to the same `year` object. Modifying one will modify all of them.

One possible solution is to use slicing to create new copies of `year`.

```
period = [year[:] for _ in range(100)]
```

Comment: Thanks again and sorry if I asked a duplicate.